# Python: Maximum recursion depth exceeded error

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following code which runs fine for a certain time but eventually fails with a “Maximum recursion depth exceeded“ error:

```
def getImg(data):
  if data and len(data) > 0:
    for entry in data:
      print "  -- Entry name", entry[‘url’]
      # eventually grab an img using the entry[‘url’] data
      time.sleep(6)
  else:
    print “no entry”
  offset = offset + 1
  queryDb(offset)

def queryDb(offset):
  offset = str(offset)
  cur.execute("SELECT name FROM mutable OFFSET " + offset + " LIMIT 1");
  result =  cur.fetchone()
  id = result[0]
  url="http://localhost:8080/?query=" + id
  r=requests.get(url)
  getImg(json.loads(r.content), artistName, gid)

queryDb(0)
```

The code is basically looping over a database table using an incrementing offset. It then calls `getImg` which will retrieve a few images (as specified in data) from a website and then call `queryDb` again with an increased index. There may be multiple entries in the data and the website has a rate limit (hence the sleep) so the best way seems to be let the loop run with the sleep in between each call and once finished then call queryDb again.

Problem is this causes the recursion error.

What’s a better way to do this whilst avoiding the recursion issue?

Comment: queryDB calls getImg, then getImg calls queryDB and so on forever...

Comment: `queryDb` calls `getImg`, which calls `queryDb`, which calls `getImg`...

Comment: Yes I know that. The question is how can I achieve this without recursion?

Comment: You are getting the error because you are recursing instead of looping. Rethink how you call your functions very carefully and stick them in a loop.

Comment: @MikeRifgin, to avoid that, you could probably call getImg in a loop.

Comment: ah ok yes so loop over the data in queryDb and just call getImg from inside that loop I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment your counter once per call to `getImg`, which means you increment it once per call to `queryDb`. So why not just do it in a loop:

```
def getImg(data):
  if data and len(data) > 0:
    for entry in data:
      print "  -- Entry name", entry['url']
      # eventually grab an img using the entry['url'] data
      time.sleep(6)
  else:
    print “no entry”

def queryDb(offset):
  offset = str(offset)
  cur.execute("SELECT name FROM mutable OFFSET " + offset + " LIMIT 1");
  result =  cur.fetchone()
  id = result[0]
  url="http://localhost:8080/?query=" + id
  r=requests.get(url)
  getImg(json.loads(r.content), artistName, gid)

offset = 0
while True:
    queryDb(offset)
    offset = offset + 1
```

This just removes the recursive call from `getImg` and puts the whole thing in a loop. It does not address any of the other issues in your code, like how you construct the DB query.

Comment: Constructing queries from strings like that is not a recommended procedure. In your case it will work fine since this is a toy example that you have full control over. In general, you would want to sanitize the parameters since for the general case you wouldn't know where they're coming from.

Comment: Yeah of course. I'd probably be using prepared statements or something similar (really new to Python) or something in the real world but this is literally a script to scrape some images.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop in `queryDb` and dont call queryDb in `getImg` :

```
def queryDb():
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM mutable");
    result =  cur.fetchall()

    for row in result:
        id = row[0]
        url="http://localhost:8080/?query=" + id
        r=requests.get(url)
        getImg(json.loads(r.content), artistName, gid)
```

Comment: This is better than my solution.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I realised as soon shortly after I posted the question. Thanks

Comment: The issue with this is that nothing calls queryDb again. After the query I need to grab the images....and once that is done I then need to call queryDb again.

Comment: Only thing I can think is to wrap the whole thing in another loop and increment offset on each iteration.